# How to fit an ellipse to a series of points in R?

Tags: r, arrays, matrix, ellipse

I am trying to fit an ellipse to a series of landmark points in R. The data is contained within an array and located at row 6. Here is a sample of the data:

```
, , Frame001.txt

          [,1]      [,2]
 [1,] 30.13947 -16.92239
 [2,] 30.34071 -16.72115
 [3,] 30.53260 -16.52926
 [4,] 30.72348 -16.33496
 [5,] 30.92572 -16.13614
 [6,] 31.13358 -15.95087
 [7,] 31.34144 -15.76561
 [8,] 31.52396 -15.58309
 [9,] 31.73182 -15.39782
[10,] 31.95565 -15.21917
[11,] 32.17287 -15.02455

, , Frame002.txt

          [,1]      [,2]
 [1,] 30.13947 -16.92239
 [2,] 30.34071 -16.72115
 [3,] 30.53260 -16.52926
 [4,] 30.72348 -16.33496
 [5,] 30.92572 -16.13614
 [6,] 31.13358 -15.95087
 [7,] 31.34144 -15.76561
 [8,] 31.52396 -15.58309
 [9,] 31.73182 -15.39782
[10,] 31.95565 -15.21917
[11,] 32.17287 -15.02455

, , Frame003.txt

          [,1]      [,2]
 [1,] 30.13947 -16.92239
 [2,] 30.34071 -16.72115
 [3,] 30.53260 -16.52926
 [4,] 30.72348 -16.33496
 [5,] 30.92572 -16.13614
 [6,] 31.13358 -15.95087
 [7,] 31.34144 -15.76561
 [8,] 31.52396 -15.58309
 [9,] 31.73182 -15.39782
[10,] 31.95565 -15.21917
[11,] 32.17287 -15.02455
```

```
dput(array)
structure(c(30.1394716184822, 30.3407126170086, 30.5325951613319, 
30.7234753517486, 30.9257187041817, 31.1335771291367, 31.3414355540918, 
31.5239596442118, 31.7318180691669, 31.9556523747537, 32.172869253912, 
-16.9223869881883, -16.7211459896618, -16.5292634453385, -16.3349610046196, 
-16.1361399024888, -15.950874784594, -15.7656096666993, -15.5830855765793, 
-15.3978204586845, -15.2191727672184, -15.0245491951204, 30.1394716184822, 
30.3407126170086, 30.5325951613319, 30.7234753517486, 30.9257187041817, 
31.1335771291367, 31.3414355540918, 31.5239596442118, 31.7318180691669, 
31.9556523747537, 32.172869253912, -16.9223869881883, -16.7211459896618, 
-16.5292634453385, -16.3349610046196, -16.1361399024888, -15.950874784594, 
-15.7656096666993, -15.5830855765793, -15.3978204586845, -15.2191727672184, 
-15.0245491951204, 30.1394716184822, 30.3407126170086, 30.5325951613319, 
30.7234753517486, 30.9257187041817, 31.1335771291367, 31.3414355540918, 
31.5239596442118, 31.7318180691669, 31.9556523747537, 32.172869253912, 
-16.9223869881883, -16.7211459896618, -16.5292634453385, -16.3349610046196, 
-16.1361399024888, -15.950874784594, -15.7656096666993, -15.5830855765793, 
-15.3978204586845, -15.2191727672184, -15.0245491951204, 30.1394716184822, 
30.3407126170086, 30.5325951613319, 30.7234753517486, 30.9257187041817, 
31.1335771291367, 31.3414355540918, 31.5239596442118, 31.7318180691669, 
31.9556523747537, 32.172869253912, -16.9223869881883, -16.7211459896618, 
-16.5292634453385, -16.3349610046196, -16.1361399024888, -15.950874784594, 
-15.7656096666993, -15.5830855765793, -15.3978204586845, -15.2191727672184, 
-15.0245491951204, 30.2524381537838, 30.3531916700196, 30.5272071629858, 
30.7171985365838, 30.8950904282038, 31.0823407740271, 31.2949254546854, 
31.4994281378246, 31.7210031127054, 31.9271974411109, 32.1276826397913, 
-16.9901669093693, -16.7538535507715, -16.5346514436846, -16.3220667630263, 
-16.1441748714063, -15.956924525583, -15.766933151985, -15.5893818716287, 
-15.4270311921735, -15.2476277008611, -15.0923291163014), dim = c(11L, 
2L, 5L), dimnames = list(NULL, NULL, c("Frame001.txt", "Frame002.txt", 
"Frame003.txt", "Frame004.txt", "Frame005.txt")))
```

I have tried using the ellipse function in R without much success. A similar question on stack exchange used conf_ell but my R isn't liking the Momocs package/can't find the conf_ell function. So the farthest I've got at this point is to create a vector with the desired points...

```
ellipse.points <- array[6,,]
```

I want the result to be an ellipse of best fit, using the points contained within the array. Any help would be much appreciated, thankyou!

Comment: The data does not seem to be reproducible. Would you be open to replacing it with something like `set.seed(1); x <- replicate(20, cbind(rnorm(11, mean=31), rnorm(11, mean=-16)))` ?

Comment: @thelatemail I'm not able to post the entire dataset, but I can make a workable subset

Comment: Your `dput()` doesn't work to copy and paste as an example. Anyway - I think this post on the web - https://lastresortsoftware.blogspot.com/2012/09/fitting-ellipse-to-point-data.html - will work for you.

Comment: @thelatemail ahh sorry about that. I've made it reproducible now, but I'll take a look at that link- thanks.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/268974/ellipse-formula-from-points

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I saw this answer, but unfortunately my R can't find the conf_ell function in the Momocs library.

Comment: But do you need conf_ell? The answer by user whuber gives the necessary theory, but see https://momx.github.io/Momocs/